# Webviews on mobile apps (iOS and Android) do no properly render icons

Tags: html, css, webview, uiwebview, android-webview

I have a font with icons defined and I am seeing inconsistent behavior in how the webkit-based mobile browsers on mobile devices.

On web, hovering the span yields the following (notice the icon properly fills it's container):

[image: web icon rendering]

On a mobile, hover the span yiles the following (notice the icon improperly fills it's container - throwing off vertical allignment):

[image]

I can't seem to find a solution to this problem beyond just using SVGs as my icons. [This webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84186) marked as resolved and won't fix doesn't seem promising.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that seems to work for me is setting the following on the span:

```
display: inline-block;
height: 1px;
```